# Where can I get he CIFS kernel add ons to run CIFS?

Tags: networking

I use a GB ROM on my Infuse 4g but it does not have CIFS built in.  I am told there is an external way of adding this in.  Does anyone have a link to this?

Comment: For accessing CIFS shares or hosting them?

Comment: I should have been a bit clearer - I am looking to be able to use a Mount Manager or COFS Manager so the shares can be mounted and act like normal folders/files for apps that just load and play files.  It seems its the mounting that is the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want it for?

There's 3 ways to get CIFS *client* support on Android:

1. 3rd party apps implementing it themselves.  Many file managers (e.g. [Astro](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro), [FX](https://market.android.com/details?id=nextapp.fx), etc.) go this route.
2. Replacement kernel with CIFS support compiled in or as a loadable module included.  This is the most common route, IME with Android phones.
3. Pre-built loadable module for the vendor's kernel.  This seems pretty rare, since the kernel interfaces can vary, and it can be difficult to find the right combination of compiler switches that yield the correct binary interface.

With 2 & 3, you still need some way of loading/activating the module and mounting shares.  This might involve editing boot scripts or loading a 3rd party program (e.g. [Mount Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twimager.cifsmanager)) to handle the mounting/unmounting.  Even then, not all your applications will nicely handle the paths to files on a network share.

Now, if you want to *serve* CIFS shares out from your phone, that's a whole different ball of wax, and there's a number of apps in the Market that will handle that.